# How do you efficiently apply a numeric operation to an array in lua?

Tags: lua, vectorization, apply

Say, I have an array

```
a = { 1, 2, 10, 15 }
```

I would like to divide each element by 3 and store the result in a new array. Is there a more efficient / elegant way of doing that than this:

```
b = { }
for i,x in pairs(a) do
  b[i] = x / 3
end
```

In R, I would simply do `b <- a/3`. Is there anything like that in lua, or maybe a way of applying a function to each element of a table?

Comment: You could consider implementing it in C. You currently don't seem to be leveraging the fact that `a` is an array; you could use `ipairs` or a numeric for loop instead of `pairs`/`next`.

Comment: Frankly, I hoped that someone has already implemented it.

Comment: So you're searching for something like [vectorize](https://github.com/wqferr/lua-vectorize) or [NumLua](https://luarocks.org/modules/luarocks/numlua)? You may want to look around on [LuaRocks](https://luarocks.org/) a bit.

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping for a standard library ;-) but both vectorize and numlua look very promising, thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [the reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/): There is no such standard library.

Comment: OK, reading the reference manual is not for the faint of heart. I barely understand it. I learned lua from ["Programming in LUA"](https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) which is not up to date, unfortunately. On the bright side, I found that writing my own lapply function is super simple in lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua is lightweight, so there is no ready-made functions, but you can create a similar function with metatable.

```
local mt_vectorization = {
    __div = function (dividend, divisor)
        local b = {}
        for i,x in pairs(dividend) do
            b[i] = x / divisor
        end
        return b
    end
}

a = setmetatable({ 1, 2, 10, 15 }, mt_vectorization)

b = a / 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by shingo, I found in the meanwhile that writing an R-style mapping function is very easy in lua:

```
function map(x, f)
  local ret = { }
  for k, v in pairs(x) do
    ret[k] = f(v)
  end
  return ret
end
```

This makes some operations easy, for example

```
a = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 10 }
map(a, function(x) return x * 2 end)
```

Comment: shingo's function *may* be faster since it doesn't suffer from function call overhead

Comment: Sure. However, mine is a different animal: you can use it with any function.